# Neo4j Relationships

Tags: neo4j

I'm  a beginner to using  Neo4j, and I've created two nodes recently.
 Nodes are: (Service1, Service2)

Service1:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV with HEADERS FROM "file:/Serv1.csv" AS line
CREATE (S:Services:Service1      {ID: TOINT (line.ID)})
set S.CCL_mv                =ToFloat (line.CCL_mv);
```

The First Node result is:

```
ID     CCL_mv
1       234.00
2          0
3          0
4      -503.00
5       413.00
6      -510.00
7          0
8       488.00
9      -488.00
10         0
11         0
12         0
13       99.23
14      -99.00
15         0
16         0
18       101.00
19         0
20         0
21       221.0
```

Service2:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV with HEADERS FROM "file:/Serv2.csv" AS line
CREATE (S: Services: Service2 {ID: TOINT (line.ID)})
        S.Depth_m         =ToFloat (line.Depth_m);
```

The Second Node result is:

```
ID       Depth_m      
1       2010.14      
2       1998.97      
3       1998,36     
4       1987,10     
5       1976,30      
6       1965,24
```

I want to hold such a relationship between (Srvice1 & Service2) 
when (CCL_mv) in Service1  is not equal to 0  (<> 0), then it should match the first row of Service2 like:

```
  Service1                     Service2 
ID     CCL_mv                 ID      Depth_m
1       234.00 =========>     1       2010.14

4      -503.00|          
5       413.00| =========>    2       1998.97   
6      -510.00|

8       488.00|    
9       488.00| =========>    3       1998,36 

13      099.23|
14     -099.00| =========>    4       1987,10


And so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. This will work fine when you have one-one mapping in both the arrays. You might need to check this query when your node count of type `Service1` is greater than of type `Service2`. I have not tested that scenario.

```
MATCH (n:Service1) WHERE n.CCL_mv <> 0
WITH collect(n) as source
WITH source, range(0, size(source)) AS index
UNWIND index as i
MATCH (m:Service2) WHERE i+1 = m.ID
WITH source[i] as from, m
CREATE (from)-[r:By_CCL]->(m) RETURN r
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code according to your fantastic method, and this gave me a brilliant solution, but if I have two or three-one mapping as I've mentioned again in the last update of my question above ^^. How can I solve this issue? 
If you don't mind, look at my question again :)?

Comment: @M.Najim - First, it is not recommended to alter the question after someone answer your original question. That makes the current answer incomplete. Second, In my opinion you can't achieve this with cypher query directly(I may be wrong). I suggest you write a simple python script(use py2neo package), iterate over nodes and execute the relationship creation query directly on node ids.